# Check and grab latest value of a certain condtion using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have created a dictionary in which it stores the information as follows:

```
dict = {'model_v001': 'In Progress',
 'model_v002': 'In Use',
 'model_v003': 'In Progress',
 'model_v004': 'In Progress',
 'model_v005': 'Approved',
 'model_v006': 'Pending'}
```

I am trying to achieve the following conditions from the contents in the dictionary:

- Grab latest 'Approved' versions if there are any
- Grab latest 'In    Progress' versions if there are any and if no
  'Approved' versions are found
- Grab latest 'Pending' versions if there are any, only if no
  'Approved' and 'In Progress' versions are found

Using the above example, I should be grabbing `model_v005` as it is the latest Approved.
So if the `model_v004`and `model_v005` status are reversed, `model_v004` will be grabbed instead.

```
keys = dict.keys()
valid_status = ['Element Approved', 'Element in Pipe']
if dict[keys[0]] in valid_status:
    #Use this version
    print 'Using this version'
else:
    #iterate and check the 'previous' version?
```

What is the best way to go around this?

Comment: There is no _latest_ since it's unordered `dict`.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered structures (at least prior to v3.6), use `collections.OrderedDict` if you want to preserve the order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by 'latest' you mean the highest version number, you could do the following:

```
original = {
    'model_v001': 'In Progress',
    'model_v002': 'In Use',
    'model_v003': 'In Progress',
    'model_v004': 'In Progress',
    'model_v005': 'Approved',
    'model_v006': 'Pending'}

def best(original):
    return max([key for key, value in original.items() if value == 'Approved']
        or [key for key, value in original.items() if value == 'In Progress']
        or [key for key, value in original.items() if value == 'Pending']
        or [None])

assert best(original) == 'model_v005'
```

It's not the most efficient, but it creates a list of all models with an 'approved' status.  If that is empty, it creates a list of models with an 'in progress' status.  If that is empty, it creates a list of models with a 'pending' status.  If that is empty, it creates a list with only 'None'. Then it gets the `max` model from whichever list it created last.

Answer (score 0):

As i noted in comment you need to refactor your so called `dict` variable(i would strongly suggest you to avoid naming variables after build-in names) to something ordered.

One option is to refactor you data into `list` of `tuple` objects.

```
from typing import Optional, List, Tuple

data = [('model_v001', 'In Progress'),
 ('model_v002', 'In Use'),
 ('model_v003', 'In Progress'),
 ('model_v004', 'In Progress'),
 ('model_v005', 'Approved'),
 ('model_v006', 'Pending')]

def return_model(data: List[Tuple[str, str]]) -> Optional[str]:
    latest = {}
    for k, v in data:
        latest[v] = k

    for status in ['Approved', 'In Progress', 'Pending']:
        if status in latest:
            return latest['Approved']
    return None
```

I used type annotations for easier understanding, which are obviously not obligatory.

What `return_model` does is it creates `dict` with latest elements per status(*key* is status and *value* is model_name), and then with your rules selects needed one. If no condition is met, then it returns `None`.

Without type annotations

```
def return_model(data):
    latest = {}
    for k, v in data:
        latest[v] = k

    for status in ['Approved', 'In Progress', 'Pending']:
        if status in latest:
            return latest['Approved']
    return None
```

Comment: Hi, so I do not have this `typing` module. Is there any other ways that I can do this?

Comment: @dissidia just omit everything that is related to type annotations. It's a working code, just with type annotations to make it more clear.